# What RAM should I add to this PC

Tags: windows, memory, desktop, desktop-computer

I want to upgrade my RAM.  I have 1 slot open.  I want to buy RAM from [aliexpress](http://www.aliexpress.com).

I have attached a screenshot of my PC System info.

[image]

Comment: @jcbermu - Why did you break the inline screenshot?

Comment: @ramhound I didn't. I wanted to show it. If you edit you can see that it's correct, but somehow is not showing the image.

Comment: @jcbermu - When I performed the edit which put it back It worked. The title change has since broken it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motherboard supports the following memory frequencies.

- PC3-6400 @ 800 MHz
- PC3-8500 @ 1066 MHz
- PC3-10600 @ 1333 MHz

Your motherboard only accepts non-ECC, un-buffered DDR3 memory.

[G41M-VS3 Specifications:](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/G41M-VS3/index.asp?cat=)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ramhound
thanks for your comment.Can you please give me any idea where i can bu y this thing(any online shop)?

Comment: @Jhon - I personally use my favorite online store.  I suggest you use your favorite online store also.  I am not going to tell you what my favorite online computer shop is, I have no idea what region of the world you live in, I have lots of choices in my region of the world

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the specifications of the motherboard on RAM

- Dual Channel DDR3 memory technology
- 2 x DDR3 DIMM slots
- Supports DDR3 1333(OC)/1066/800 non-ECC, un-buffered memory
- Max. capacity of system memory: 8GB*

You should get rid of the Ram stick you have and buy a pair of sticks.

4GB per stick at 1333. (non-ECC)

**Never mix RAM sticks.**  If you are using multiple RAM sticks they should be bought as a dual channel kit.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'never mix' by any means but it is always better to buy pairs.

Comment: @Cand3r Yeah I guess it is quite an extreme.  I have just come across problems in the past when mixing RAM which are horrible to track down if both sticks are technically working individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your motherboard specs [here](http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/g41m-vs3/), it supports non-ECC/un-buffered DDR3 RAM at 800, 1066, and 1333(Overclocked) speeds with a max capacity of 8GB.

Your current RAM stick is showing 398mhz so that would be a DDR3 800 stick.  Your computer will only run as fast as the slowest piece of hardware so there isn't much point in adding anything faster than DDR3/800 but any of the above speeds will work as long as you get a 4GB stick.

If you can get a 6-6-6-15 timed stick that would be the best but is not very important.  The x-x-x-x can be listed as CAS latency and may only have 1 number, in that case, look for a CAS latency of 6.

TLDR: You are looking for any 4GB DDR3 800/1066/1333 stick of RAM.

Comment: Hi @Cand3r 
if i increase the Ram Should it Help to make my PC Faster?Yes,i am looking for DDR3 Ram But don't know which should i buy 4gb or 2gb (not experience in this field).Any Recommendation?

Comment: @Jhon - You likely will not see a very little speed improvement with only 4 GB of additional memory.  So if you have 4 GB now, going to only 6 GB, really would result even less of a speed improvement.